# 500 Server Error with Large Integer Calculations

Tags: php, math, integer

I have a function to spit out random locations with XYZ space. I am getting a 500 internal server error whenever my radius exceeds 1e+06. My cuboid location populator doesn't seem to have the same issue, which it simply compares new locations to the dimension defined as maximum limits. I am not really great with maths and suspect I am doing something wrong with calculations, which may be killing PHP with too large of integers or something? It is a 64bit system, however.

```
/*
 * $loc = Point of Origin
 * $r = Maximum radius
 * $ylimit = Limit locations on Y Axis
 */
function basic_spheroid_point( $loc, $r, $ylimit = 0 ) {
    
    list ($cx, $cy, $cz) = $loc;
    
    static $cnt = 0;
    
    $dx = randint( -$r, $r );
    $dy = randint( -$r, $r );
    $dz = randint( -$r, $r );
    
    $dd = sqrt( $dx * $dx + $dy * $dy + $dz * $dz );
    
    if ( $dd > $r ) {
        
        $cnt++;
        
        if ( $cnt <= 10000 ) 
            
            return basic_spheroid_point( $loc, $r, $ylimit );
        
    }
    
    $cnt = 0;
    
    $dx = $r * $dx / $dd;
    $dy = $r * $dy / $dd;
    $dz = $r * $dz / $dd;
    
    $loc = array( $cx + $dx, $cy + $dy, $cz + $dz );
    
    if ( $ylimit > 0 ) {
    
        if ( $loc[1] < $ylimit && $loc[1] > -$ylimit ) {

            return $loc;
            
        } else {
            
            return basic_spheroid_point( $loc, $r, $ylimit );
            
        }
        
    } else {
        
        return $loc;
        
    }

}

function randint($min = 0, $max = 0) {
    
    if ( function_exists( 'random_int' ) ):
    
        return ( $min === 0 && $max === 0 ) ? random_int(0, PHP_INT_MAX) : random_int($min, $max);
        
    elseif (function_exists('mt_rand')):
    
        return ( $min === 0 && $max === 0 ) ? mt_rand() : mt_rand($min, $max);
        
    endif;
    
    return ( $min === 0 && $max === 0 ) ? rand() : rand($min, $max);

}
```

This may already be answered, but I wasn't getting anything in searches or in the similar questions que.

Comment: Can you look at the server logs to see the actual error? I suspect a recursion 10 000 levels deep might cause a stack overflow error.

Comment: It's not creating an error_log in the project folder, and nothing appearing in the other error_logs in parent or root folder. Just old errors.

Comment: `error_reporting( E_ALL );` is on, and the application is allowed to use 2gb of memory, no execution limit, and 2056 nesting levels. As there is a lot of recursion in picking random locations if you want a lot. PS it's for baking purposes so not too worried of impact.

Comment: I was thinking of using BCMath extension, but not sure if that's necessary and it's a bit of work to convert the whole thing, especially if not necessary.

Comment: Please specify exactly what's the error - on which line error occurs.

Comment: Server is not getting an error, it's crashing (500 internal server error) there is no PHP error being written to logs. This was stated already.

Answer (score 0):

You exceed [PHP_INT_MAX](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php). Rewrite code to use [BC Math](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension with arbitrary precision.

Comment: I was afraid of having to use this. But I actually figured out how to get it going. For one I actually noticed if I use `PHP_INT_MAX` I would probably be hitting the max, so I defined `MAX_INT` which is now `PHP_INT_MAX-1`. Second `if ( $loc[1] < $ylimit && $loc[1] > -$ylimit ) {` should be using OR `||` not `&&.` That sends the script to continue until the server runs out of resources.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty simple. Aside from a couple other issues, the real reason was

```
   if ( $loc[1] < $ylimit && $loc[1] > -$ylimit ) {
```

which uses `&&` and causes the script to continue to use the function until there are no resources left. It should be an OR operator `||`

Comment: It's great you solved your problem, but IMO you should anyway learn where to find server logs in situations with 500 Server Error in order to quickly determine what exactly the error is. Here's a random blog post from a google search that may help you: https://blog.codeasite.com/how-do-i-find-apache-http-server-log-files/

Comment: This is only relevant if a user has access to the server with such privileges. Which, frankly, isn't most the Internet's hosts [for consumers].

Comment: It's also safe to assume with no execution limit, or abort, and an infinite loop, the apache server is straight crashing. What the script is actually doing is pretty intense, and something you'd see in a 3D DCC app.